# mongodb - understanding read operations

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Suppose I have a collection:

```
   db.person.insert(
   [
     {
       _id: 3,
       name: { first: 'Grace', last: 'Hopper' },
       title: 'Rear Admiral',
       birth: new Date('Dec 09, 1906'),
       death: new Date('Jan 01, 1992'),
       contribs: [ 'UNIVAC', 'compiler', 'FLOW-MATIC', 'COBOL' ],
       awards: [
                 {
                   award: 'Computer Sciences Man of the Year',
                   year: 1999,
                   by: 'Data Processing Management Association'
                 },
                 {
                   award: 'Distinguished Fellow',
                   year: 1973,
                   by: ' British Computer Society'
                 },
                 {
                   award: 'W. W. McDowell Award',
                   year: 1976,
                   by: 'IEEE Computer Society'
                 },
                 {
                   award: 'National Medal of Technology',
                   year: 1991,
                   by: 'United States'
                 }
               ]
     },
     {
       _id: 4,
       name: { first: 'Kristen', last: 'Nygaard' },
       birth: new Date('Aug 27, 1926'),
       death: new Date('Aug 10, 2002'),
       contribs: [ 'OOP', 'Simula' ],
       awards: [
                 {
                   award: 'Rosing Prize',
                   year: 1999,
                   by: 'Norwegian Data Association'
                 },
                 {
                   award: 'Turing Award',
                   year: 2001,
                   by: 'ACM'
                 },
                 {
                   award: 'IEEE John von Neumann Medal',
                   year: 2001,
                   by: 'IEEE'
                 }
               ]
     },

   ]
)
```

Question:how to fetch person's name who have received an award on 1999?

```
SQL Query would be : Select first , last from person where year = 1999;
```

NOTE: Yes, It's a stupid question. But I am still trying to understand how NoSQL works. I am trying to replicate some select query from relational database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mongoDB documentation has a section on [SQL to MongoDB mapping](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/#select). But essentially you want :

```
db.person.find({"awards.year":1999},{"name.first":1, "name.last":1, _id:0})
```

Answer (score 1):

Never-mind I managed to do it

```
db.bios.find( {awards : {$elemMatch: {year:1991}}} , {'name': 1} )
```

Comment: This answer is only correct if you want to match within the same array element